# How to remove city field from admin "Create New Order" Billing Address?

Tags: magento-1.9, address

Hi I am working with magento 1.9.3

In admin panel I need to remove **City** field form **Create New Order** page (Both Billing and Shipping Address).

Can anyone suggest me please how I can do that?

For your convenient here is the screenshot:

[image]